# Loading module outside zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am using ZEND 3 and I need to use a module in ordinary PHP file outside framework. How can it be done - make instance of the module and call some method, please?

Comment: put it in your vendor folder.

Comment: I need to call Zend module outside of Zend framework.